# How does one gracefully kill a process in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell

I know one can just go into task manager and kill a process; but like not ejecting your thumb drive before pulling it out of the socket, one should notify the process it's being killed first if possible.

So my question is how does one gracefully kill a process in Windows?  Ideally using Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://superuser.com/questions/959364/on-windows-how-can-i-gracefully-ask-a-running-program-to-terminate

taskkill will do it, it sends WM_CLOSE messages to the target process.

Caveat - If a process is hung, it wouldn't be able to respond to your request to gracefully exit anyway.

Comment: This also only applies to processes that have windows... i.e. not console or service processes.  Basically this is the same thing as either clicking the X button on the window or the task manager also tries this first.

Comment: @psusi How do you gracefully kill a process with no window?  A service for instance?

Comment: @leeand00, there is no general method, but services in particular interface with the service control manager which can pass them a command to shut down.

Comment: @leeand00 - for an arbitrary app, it has to surface and support some method for doing so. If the app authors didn't handle that case, you can't.